# How to Block an IP Address on Android

Tags: networking

There's an IP address keeping ICMP my network every minute.
I've already blocked the IP on my router, I'd like to know how to configure traffic control on Android if possible.

Please tell me if there's a way or app to control access from/to a specific IP address.

Comment: The incoming ICMP is IPv4 or IPv6? If it is V4 then it can not pass your router anyway.

Comment: @Robert it's V4, my network is under the CGNAT of ISP. It seems  my WIFI connections has got SynDrop DoS attacked, which I'm not pretty sure though.